# My Internal SSD is Not Showing Up in Diskutil

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I ereased current MacOS system and tried to setup new version from scratch. But Macbook can't show internal SSD in diskutil anymore. I can't access my SSD in Macbook. Whan I tried until now and results:

1) I was have bootcamp in it and I tried to access to Windows on Macbook, I accessed, but Macbook's own firmware couldn't see it anyway.

2) I have tried SSD and tested everything on it (GTP opening, format settings etc.) everything works very fine for SSD.

3) I have tried install a MacOS to my flash disk from internet recover system, it worked.

4) I have booted 2 different USB sticks (3.0, 2.0) they both never seen as bootable but I can see them in disk utils.

5) I tried reset thing on Macbook (CMD + Option + R + P) didn't work for me.

6) I tried 4 different DMG files with 4 different versions of MacOS (by using TransMac) and I tried to boot all of them on Mac but never worked.

7) Everything was fine until I pressed to "Erase" button on Disk Utility in CMD + R at startup. I just wanted to reset everything and install a fresh setup but that locked my whole day.

I have tried everything what I can find on the internet but it never see any internal storage anyway.
(I mean OS never sees it but bootcamp was still working when even OS can't see it. Until I reset SSD on my Windows PC, I can access to Bootcamp Windows from Macbook Pro after Erasing MacOS Catalina.)

Thank you everyone...

Comment: Tried these:  https://pureinfotech.com/create-macos-bootable-usb-windows/
https://techiestechguide.com/internal-ssd-is-not-showing-in-macbook-while-booting/
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244219/new-uninitialised-ssd-not-showing-in-disk-utility

Comment: There's exactly same situation with me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384793/macbook-internal-ssd-not-showing-up-in-system-information-or-disk-utility/390209#390209
But there's no solution of course.

Comment: Of course you can see your SSD, BootCamp is just another partition on your Mac SSD. Go ahead and press Command + R and click on the Apple icon. Click Startup Disk and select your macOS disk. Of course you have to have macOS installed on it. Make sure the disk is formatted APFS.

Comment: This question is confusing.  Can you summarize what you want the end result to be?  Do you want a clean install of macOS while preserving bootcamp or do you want an install of just macOS?  Which Mac model do you have?  Is your data backed up?

Comment: It's Macbook Pro 2015, I wanted to clean setup MacOS at the beginning. Now I just want to see my SSD on any MacOS. I'm using MacOS on Flash USB (32 GB) for now. SSD health is perfect and works on Windows PC and just like I told before, until I deleted Windows from my SSD it was working without MacOS. (By bootcamp) And I wasn't able to see that part of SSD too when I open Mac's Bios. That's the most funny part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I have an NVME SSD because of that Yosemite or El Capitan can't see it. I just created an High Sierra boot USB and that solved my problem.